# How to tweak app.php file for deployment a Symfony2 app and gets the best performance

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, apc, symfony-2.7

I will deploy a Symfony2 app in a few days so I am asking a few things about `app.php` file and setting up a right production environment. So here is the default `app.php` file content:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
// in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
// also using APC.
/*
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Here are my doubts:

- Should I enable the APC loader? This will improve my app speed or what this will do?
- If I enable the APC cache loader which will be the right command to clean the APC cache?
- Should I require `AppCache.php` and remove `AppKernel.php`?
- I am using PHP 5.6 and have Zend OPCache enabled, should I install and enable also APC Cache and use this instead default Zend OPCache?

If you've any prod ready `app.php` file, can you share it and also your ideas and suggestions?

Comment: If you use OPC: 1.no, 2.?, 3.no, 4.no.

Comment: This is nice, why the down vote? This is not a good question?

Comment: I'm not down voted, just reply for question, I think it's not worth to install apc while we have opc by default. I up vote now for overcome votes :D

Comment: @malcolm Thx I didn't said you was the one for the down vote instead other does without read the question and at least try to show me why I am wrong or why he/she think it's fine to down vote